# How do I centre a <div> in the middle of a container?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a cart page for an eCommerce site and I want all the items in the cart to be shown in a table format. This is how I am going to present it:

[image]

I want the name, quantity and price of the product row to be in the middle of the container and I have tried to do this using align-content but it doesn't seem to work:

This is the html what is wrong?

```css
.productRowContainer {
  /* holds the products added from the cart */
  width: 100%;
  height: 196px;
}

.cartItemContainer {
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.dataContainer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 22px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Product Row (will be repeated) -->
<div class="productRowContainer">
  <!-- holds labels for cart -->
  <div class="cartItemContainer">
    <img src="{{ asset('img/iamlush/shop/ShopDark.jpg') }}" style="width: 60%;">
  </div>

  <div class="cartItemContainer">
    <div class="dataContainer">
      <p>Name</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="cartItemContainer">
    <div class="dataContainer">
      <p>Quantity</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="cartItemContainer">
    <div class="dataContainer">
      <p>Price</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: For tabular data, use a `<table>`!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `align-items` property needs to be set on the `productRowContainer`. You also forgot `display: flex` on the container.

In the future, I recommend using http://flexbox.buildwithreact.com/ to play around with flexbox layouts. It really helps !

```css
.productRowContainer {
  /* holds the products added from the cart */
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  height: 196px;
  align-items: center;
}

.cartItemContainer {
  width: 25%;
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.dataContainer {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!-- Product Row (will be repeated) -->
<div class="productRowContainer">
  <!-- holds labels for cart -->
  <div class="cartItemContainer">
    <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/196" style="width: 60%;">
  </div>

  <div class="cartItemContainer">
    <div class="dataContainer">
      <p>Name</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="cartItemContainer">
    <div class="dataContainer">
      <p>Quantity</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="cartItemContainer">
    <div class="dataContainer">
      <p>Price</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `height: 100%;` to `.cartItemContainer` and it shall align to middle.

```
.cartItemContainer {
      width: 25%;
      height: 100%; /* Add this line */
...
```

```css
.productRowContainer {
  /* holds the products added from the cart */
  width: 100%;
  height: 196px;
}

.cartItemContainer {
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%; /* Add this line */
  float: left;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.dataContainer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 22px;
}
```

```html
<!-- Product Row (will be repeated) -->
<div class="productRowContainer">
  <!-- holds labels for cart -->
  <div class="cartItemContainer">
    <img src="{{ asset('img/iamlush/shop/ShopDark.jpg') }}" style="width: 60%; height: 196px;">
  </div>

  <div class="cartItemContainer">
    <div class="dataContainer">
      <p>Name</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="cartItemContainer">
    <div class="dataContainer">
      <p>Quantity</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="cartItemContainer">
    <div class="dataContainer">
      <p>Price</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```